# Iterate over columns to slice dataset

Tags: python, pandas, loops, slice

I have the following dataset:
Columns named: 2,3,4...9 are filled with topic names that overlap with each other. Pageviews is an outcome variable.

```
        2                           3                       Pageviews
0       Financial Services          Consumer Products       4106.0
1       Consumer Products           ...                     3368.0
2       Consumer Products           ...                     1025.0
3       Collaboration               ...                     7840.0
4       Future of Supply Chains     ...                     2076.0
```

I would like to slice each topic column (2,3, 4, ...) together with `Pageviews` and append them so as to create only one dataframe with 1 topic column and `Pageviews`.

I am used to looping in Stata where you could loop through the name of the columns using `x`, but I understand it is totally different with Pyhton.

I started with

```
for x in range(2, 9):
    df_x = df[['Pageviews',  df.x]]
```

but Python does not recognize `df.x`

How do you loop through column names? And is it possible to use the iterator to create new dataframes?

Thanks!

EDIT

My desired output is

```
                                       Col        Pageviews
0                           Financial Services      4106.0
1                            Consumer Products      3368.0
2                            Consumer Products      1025.0
3                                 Collaboration     7840.0
4                      Future of Supply Chains      2076.0
5                          Future of Reporting      2123.0
6                    Sustainability Management     15576.0
7                                 Human Rights        52.0
8                                      BSR News      903.0
9                       Energy and Extractives      1232.0
10                                  HERproject       616.0
11                   Sustainability Management     10697.0
```

where col is the result of appending columns 2, 3, 4... and Pageviews is the result of appending the respective Pageviews columns..

Comment: Could you show how you expect your output DataFrame to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `melt`

```
df.melt('Pageviews').drop('variable',1)
Out[644]: 
    Pageviews                 value
0        1210      ConsumerProducts
1        1528         Collaboration
2        1716     FinancialServices
3        1403         Collaboration
4        1090      ConsumerProducts
5        1210      ConsumerProducts
6        1528  FutureofSupplyChains
7        1716      ConsumerProducts
8        1403     FinancialServices
9        1090  FutureofSupplyChains
10       1210     FinancialServices
11       1528     FinancialServices
12       1716         Collaboration
13       1403  FutureofSupplyChains
14       1090     FinancialServices
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for some sort of [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas.DataFrame.stack) method rather than iteration (generally, when working with dataframes, iteration is a last resort, as there are usually vectorized methods to achieve most data reorganization tasks).

Take the example dataframe:

```
>>> df
                    0                        1                        2  \
0   Consumer Products        Consumer Products       Financial Services   
1       Collaboration  Future of Supply Chains       Financial Services   
2  Financial Services        Consumer Products            Collaboration   
3       Collaboration       Financial Services  Future of Supply Chains   
4   Consumer Products  Future of Supply Chains       Financial Services   

   Pageviews  
0       1210  
1       1528  
2       1716  
3       1403  
4       1090
```

You can do the following:

```
new_df = (df.set_index('Pageviews')
          .stack()
          .reset_index(0))

>>> new_df
    Pageviews                        0
0        1210        Consumer Products
1        1210        Consumer Products
2        1210       Financial Services
3        1528            Collaboration
4        1528  Future of Supply Chains
5        1528       Financial Services
6        1716       Financial Services
7        1716        Consumer Products
8        1716            Collaboration
9        1403            Collaboration
10       1403       Financial Services
11       1403  Future of Supply Chains
12       1090        Consumer Products
13       1090  Future of Supply Chains
14       1090       Financial Services
```

Comment: Hm, now that I read your answer I'm not sure what OP was actually asking ..

Comment: I agree it's a bit unclear... That was my interpretation